# C++ Reading integers from .cfg file

Tags: c++, string, integer, fstream, getline

I am trying to read 3 integers from a .cfg file into 3 different variables in C++ but am having no luck getting the correct values stored in the variables.

The .cfg file is stored locally and reads like so:

```
25
16
50
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream inFile("config.cfg");
    int foo, bar, baz;

    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line, temp;

        while (getline(inFile, line))
        {
            std::istringstream stream(line);

            //foo
            getline(stream, temp);
            foo = std::stoi(temp);

            //bar
            getline(stream, temp);
            bar = std::stoi(temp);

            //baz
            getline(stream, temp);
            baz = std::stoi(temp);
        }
    } std::cout << foo << " " << bar << " " << baz;
    return 0;
}
```

I have been trying to grab the integers line-by-line as strings before converting them to ints with stoi and finally storing them.

However, when I print the values with cout I get:

```
4201632 6422400 4201520
```

Clearly something is wrong with my method but I am not sure what. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your file isn't opened, you go straight to the `cout` line and display the values of uninitialized variables. So: Do you successfully open the file?

Comment: `while (getline(inFile, line))` and then from that line, `getline(stream, temp);`. OK, but now what's left for `getline(stream, temp);`? If you don't see the problem, think on it for a few moment.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm you are right, it seems the file is not opening, so the variables remain uninitialized. I've used this method to open and read files before though with no problem so I cannot understand why it isn't working this time? Is there a different method for opening .cfg files than for .txt and .csv? Everything I read seemed to indicate they are the same

Comment: You may have run up against the Working Directory. Whatever tool you are using may have the program looking for config.cfg in some folder other than the one you're expecting it to look in.

Comment: C++ file streams don't give a <expletive deleted> a file is called or even what's in it. They're all the same at the level of a file stream.

Comment: @user4581301 Ok, I ran program again using absolute path rather than relative for config file and this got the file open. Now though, all 3 variables store the value 50. I am guessing this goes back to your first point, although I'm struggling to understand the problem. By the time the program is ready to store the values, 50 is all that is left to be read?

Comment: Think about what's going on. Draw a little flowchart if you have to. You have a while loop that will execute 3 times, once per line. Inside the body of the loop you try to read the line into three separate variables. That's 9 reads. Since there are only three values to be read, six reads are doomed to fail.